# How to use an Injectable Service in a custom Validator

Tags: angular, function, angular-services, angular-validation, angular-validator

I have this Scenario:-

I am creating a customvalidator in my app which uses a service to get Data

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { IndianStatesAndCitiesService } from './indianstatesandcities.service';
export function SpecificState(control: AbstractControl) {
    let iss : IndianStatesAndCitiesService;
    let getiss : string[] = [];
    for(let i in iss.getStatesAndCities()){
        getiss.push(i);
    }
    if (control.value !== undefined && (getiss.includes(control.value))) {
        return { 'specificState': true };
    }
    return null;
}
```

But it is throwing following Error:-

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getStatesAndCities' of undefined
    at SpecificState (specificstate.validator.ts:6)
```

Is there anyway i could use the angular service inside that function??

Comment: Have you injected IndianStatesAndCitiesService this service in your constructor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inject custom service into a custom Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42646440/inject-custom-service-into-a-custom-validator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace this

```
let iss : IndianStatesAndCitiesService;
```

with

```
var iss = new IndianStatesAndCitiesService();
```

you haven't created an object of service try this